# Youtube API v3 Client error occurred: HTTP Error: Unable to connect failed to open stream

Tags: php, youtube-api, fopen, youtube-data-api

I'm using youtube api v3 but when I try to search anything using this it give me the error.

```
  An client error occurred: HTTP Error: Unable to connect: 'fopen(compress.zlib://https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&amp;q=national+songs&amp;maxResults=20&amp;type=video&amp;key=AIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7anA) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: operation failed'
```

I checked my `php.ini` files in my wamp server these are allow `fopen url` `allow_url_fopen = on`

Here is the simple search code.

```
<?php
require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
  $DEVELOPER_KEY = 'AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa7anA';

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setDeveloperKey($DEVELOPER_KEY);
  // Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
  $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

  try {
    // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
    // query term.
    $searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
      'q' => $_GET['q'],
      'maxResults' => 20,
      'type' => 'video',
    ));
     .......
     .......
```

when I try to run only this `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&amp;q=national+songs&amp;maxResults=20&amp;type=video&amp;key=AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7anA`
It will show this.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

I checked daily quota limit in `console api` but here it is fine. It didn't show anything about exceeding limit.
I also create new api key with other email but the same error.
Why this error occur Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked that zlib is also enabled? It looks like the error you posted is from the browser; so, is there anything more in the wamp log file?

Comment: @Nick I checked `phpinfo()`   `zlib` is enabled.
But if I only try this one on browser `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&amp;q=national+songs&amp;maxResults=20&amp;type=video&amp;key=AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7anA` it give the above error. it seems that `API` is not working.

Comment: Did you also look in the WAMP access and error log files to see if there is any further detail about the error?